# Linking errors - new to templates

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H_
#define LINKED_LIST_H_

#include<memory>

template <class T>
class LinkedList{
public:
//
LinkedList() {}
LinkedList(const T &data);
LinkedList(const T &data, LinkedList &node);
LinkedList(const LinkedList &object);
LinkedList &operator=(const LinkedList &object);

~LinkedList() {}

std::shared_ptr<LinkedList> push_back(const T& data);

private:
T data;
std::unique_ptr<LinkedList> link;

std::unique_ptr<LinkedList> LinkFactory(const LinkedList &node);

std::shared_ptr<LinkedList> CreateStartNode(const T &data);
std::shared_ptr<LinkedList> CreateNode(const T &data, const LinkedList &node);
};
//
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const T &data) : data(data), link(nullptr) {}
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const T &data, LinkedList &node) : data(data) { this->link =           
LinkFactory(node); }
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T> &object) : data(object.data)       
link(object.link) {}
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::operator=(const LinkedList<T> &object){
data = object.data;
link = object.link;
return *this;
}

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<LinkedList<T>> LinkFactory(const LinkedList<T> &node){
return std::unique_ptr<LinkedList<T>>(new LinkedList(node))
}
//
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>> LinkedList<T>::CreateStartNode(const T &data){
return std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>>(new LinkedList(data));
}
//
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>> CreateNode(const T &data, const LinkedList<T> &node){
return std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>>(new LinkedList(data, node));
}

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>> LinkedList<T>::push_back(const T &data){
//
if(this == 0){
    // create new node
    return CreateStartNode(data);
}else{
    // add a node
    return CreateNode(data, *this);
}
}

#endif
```

Here is the linking error:

```
 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: class std::tr1::shared_ptr<class   
 LinkedList<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class  
 std::allocator<char> > > > __thiscall LinkedList<class std::basic_string<char,struct 
 std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::CreateNode(class 
 std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > 
 const &,class LinkedList<class std::basic_string<char,struct 
 std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > const &)" (?CreateNode@?
 $LinkedList@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@AAE?AV?
 $shared_ptr@V?$LinkedList@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
 $allocator@D@2@@std@@@@@tr1@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
 $allocator@D@2@@4@ABV1@@Z)
 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
 1>
 1>Build FAILED.
```

I am rather new to template use and did not formally learn it but rather hack-n-slash through the web rather than read a chapter. Where have I gone wrong with this code and what corrections must be made to produce the most professional code possible?

Comment: Do you have everything in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of CreateNode function is not in LinkedList scope.

Yours

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>> 
CreateNode(const T &data, const LinkedList<T> &node)
{
return std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>>(new LinkedList(data, node));
}
```

Should be

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>> 
LinkedList<T>::CreateNode(const T &data, const LinkedList<T> &node)
{
return std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>>(new LinkedList(data, node));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a member function outside a class definition, you need to qualify the member name with `LinkedList<T>::` to indicate that it's a member; otherwise, it instead declares a new non-member function.

You have forgotten the qualification on the definitions of `CreateNode` and `LinkFactory`:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<LinkedList<T>> LinkedList<T>::LinkFactory(const LinkedList<T> &node){
//                    Add this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return std::unique_ptr<LinkedList<T>>(new LinkedList(node));
}
```

Comment: Thank you all ... I had prefixed the other members with 'LinkedList<T>::' but not this one.  Here is another question.  I cleaned up remaining compile-time issues and the dreaded unique_ptr no copy/no assign has popped up and my unfamiliarity with move constructors or hiding copy constructors has crept up again.  Do you have any recommendations or suggestions?

Comment: @user633658: Generally, if you want to pass an object to a move constructor (or anything else expecting an *rvalue* reference), then you need to explicitly move it: `Thing moved(std::move(old_thing));`. If you have a specific bit of code you're struggling with, I suggest asking a new question about it.